# Orphaned TCP connections after closing client and server

Tags: java, tcp, client-server

I implemented a client server application in java and it works fine . Now if i do a `netstat -a` in the shell to see the active connections i see that there are alot of orphaned connections of the following form

```
TCP 127.0.0.1:54725 Sin-Host:0 LISTENING
```

For example if i create a server on port 58185 like below

```
TCP 127.0.0.1:58185 Sin-Host:0 LISTENING
```

When a client connects to it i get two connections like as follows

```
TCP 127.0.0.1:58185 Sin-Host:0 LISTENING
TCP 127.0.0.1:58185 Sin-Host:58187 ESTABLISHED
TCP 127.0.0.1:58187 Sin-Host:58185 ESTABLISHED
```

Now when i close both my client and server the first connection remains ( namely in `LISTENING` state  not `TIMED_WAIT` )

I think there is no reason for the first connection to remain when i have closed both the client and server . Is this a bug ? It doesnt really affect my program but i just want to know so that i know its impact .

```
**EDIT : How long do these orphans last**
```

I rebooted my system and all the orphans are gone . I repeated the test and see that orphans remain even after application shut down but go away after system reboot .

Maybe i guess this is some system settings that prevents it from going in the first place .?

Comment: Define 'close both my client and server'. Did you actually exit the process in each case?

Comment: @EJP by `close` i mean i killed my eclipse instance running the server by closing the entire eclipse .

Comment: How long does it keep listening?

Comment: @rockstar But does that exit the client and server processes? On the evidence, clearly not.

Comment: @EJP Isn't it due to the fact that the TCP connection remain in `Timeout` state for a period of time after connection is closed? Especially if the connection is terminated forcefully

Comment: @VishalK if the connection is in ``Timed out`` it wont say ``Listening``

Comment: Closing eclipse may not be enough as your program is running in a separate process. Have you checked that your program is really terminated?

Comment: @UwePlonus  i think you are correct . Closing eclipse is not enough . Since i did a fork so the process remains . ! This explains why it does away after system boot :-) Thanks

Comment: @VishalK No. There is no `Timeout` state. You are presumably referring to the `TIME-WAIT` state. This question is about the `LISTENING` and `ESTABLISHED` states. There's no evidence here that anything has been terminated forcibly, except Eclipse, which doesn't appear to have had any effect on the running applications.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a line like

```
serverSocket.accept();
```

in you code the connection with `LISTENING` will remain.

The `accept()` leads to the `LISTENING` state of the port.

Both of the `ESTABLSHED` lines are for the active connection.

Comment: Not if the entire process exits, which is the actual point at issue here. In any case it is completely untrue to say 'the `accept()` leads to the LISTENING state of the port'. The C `listen()` API causes the LISTENING state: it is called by the constructor of `ServerSocket`. -1

Comment: @EJP Please read my comment on the original question. It seems like the program was still running therefore my analysis seems to be correct...

Comment: No, it isn't correct, and I've already told you why. Your answer is based on a false premiss. I repeat. It isn't the `accept()` that causes this condition, it is the existence and the non-closure of the `ServerSocket`.